# Django : How to fill Charfield with the button value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a simple python webapp  that stacks 2 tables.

First the columns of both tables are listed as buttons on top of the page (lets call it `column buttons`).

Next we have input field row (with 2 inputs), `Input 1` --> The columns to be stacked, separated by commas. `Input 2` --> The column name of the Output table. i.e each row represents a column-combination.

I'm good until here.

Challenge: I want to auto-fill `Input 1` (with the column names) while I click the respective `column buttons`. Instead of typing it manually

I'm unable to find the options in Django to achieve this yet. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Django model for your tables and you're passing the column names to the template:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    column1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    column2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # ... other columns
```

In your views:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import YourModel

def your_view(request):
    columns = [field.name for field in YourModel._meta.get_fields()]
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'columns': columns})
```

In your template (your_template.html):

```
<!-- your_template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Web App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Column Buttons -->
    {% for column in columns %}
        <button onclick="fillInput('{{ column }}')">{{ column }}</button>
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- Input Fields -->
    <form>
        <label for="input1">Input 1:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1">

        <label for="input2">Input 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2">
    </form>

    <script>
        // Function to fill Input 1 with column names
        function fillInput(columnName) {
            var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
            input1.value += columnName + ',';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you!